# How to set SRS to 'EPSG:4326' in geotools?

Tags: postgis, java, geotools

I have the following code, referenced from my previous post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52554587/add-new-column-attribute-to-the-shapefile-and-save-it-to-database-using-geotools. So what I am trying to do here is basically set the `SRS value to EPSG:4326` which is intially `0` (ST_SRID(geom)). In postgis its simple to update which is like this:

```
UPDATE spatial_table
-- update the srid
SET geom  = ST_SetSRID(geom, 4326)
-- only alters rows that don't already have an srid assigned
WHERE ST_SRID(geom) = 0;
```

But since I am using geotools to store into the postgis, I want to know if there is any way i could **set the SRS** while saving it into the database.

I tried the following but didn't work:

```
FileDataStore ds = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(new File(FilePath));
        SimpleFeatureType schema = ds.getSchema();
        System.out.println("Schema getName :"+ schema.getName());
        System.out.println("Schema getTypeName :"+ schema.getTypeName());
        // create new schema
        SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder builder = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
        builder.setName(schema.getTypeName().replaceAll("%20", "_").toLowerCase());
       // builder.setCRS( DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84); //didn't work
       // builder.setCRS(CRS.decode("EPSG:4326",true)); //didn't work
        builder.setSuperType((SimpleFeatureType) schema.getSuper());
        builder.addAll(schema.getAttributeDescriptors());

         System.out.println("After replacement :"+ schema.getName().toString().replaceAll("%20", "_").replaceAll(" ", "_"));
        // add new attribute(s)
        //builder.add("shapeID", String.class)
        // build new schema
        SimpleFeatureType nSchema = builder.buildFeatureType();
        System.out.println("Shapefile table info : " + nSchema);

        //System.out.println("Adding column attr to shpfile");
        // loop through features adding new attribute
        List<SimpleFeature> features = new ArrayList<>();
        try (SimpleFeatureIterator itr = ds.getFeatureSource().getFeatures().features()) {
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                SimpleFeature f = itr.next();
                SimpleFeature f2 = DataUtilities.reType(nSchema, f);

               // f2.setAttribute("shapeID", ID);
                //System.out.println(f2);
                features.add(f2);
            }
        }
        Properties params = new Properties();
        // Configure the PostGIS database here
        params.put("user", "test");
        params.put("passwd", "postgres");
        params.put("port", "5432");
        params.put("host", "127.0.0.1");
        params.put("database", "testdb");
        params.put("dbtype", "postgis");
       // params.put(PostgisNGDataStoreFactory.LOOSEBBOX, true );

        DataStore dataStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(params);
    try{
    if (dataStore == null) {
        System.out.println("Failed to connect to PostGIS");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    String tableName = nSchema.getTypeName();
    user.settableName(tableName);
    boolean exists = false;
    String[] names = dataStore.getTypeNames();
    for (String name : names) {
        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(tableName)) {
            exists = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!exists) {
        dataStore.createSchema(nSchema);
    }
    SimpleFeatureSource source = dataStore.getFeatureSource(tableName);
    if (source instanceof SimpleFeatureStore) {
        SimpleFeatureStore store = (SimpleFeatureStore) source;
        store.addFeatures(DataUtilities.collection(features));
        System.out.println("Successfully created a database");
        flag = true;
    } else {
        System.err.println("Unable to connect to database");
        flag = false;
    }
   }
    finally{
            dataStore.dispose();
            }

      return flag;
  }
```

**EDIT:**
 1. `builder.setCRS( DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84)` // I am sure whether this is the way I need to set, but just a try based on the example code.

2. `builder.setCRS(CRS.decode("EPSG:4326",true));` // CRS.decode() the method is no longer available. The import dependency is as follows:
   `org.geotools.data.Parameter.CRS;`

I am using geotools dependency as follows:

```
   <artifactId>GeoDemo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
   <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <geotools.version>20-SNAPSHOT</geotools.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>it.geosolutions</groupId>
            <artifactId>geoserver-manager</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-shapefile</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-swing</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-jdbc-postgis</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: please say why the 2 commented out lines didn't work. Also we need to see the code where you create the postgis table.

Comment: @IanTurton updated the question based on ur inputs...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This only occurs if you are processing shapefiles with no `.prj` file, try to avoid doing this as they are just collections of random numbers. **Always prefer going back and fixing the process or person generating the dataset.**

Any way if you are stuck dealing with poor quality data then you can fix it by changing the `GeometryDescriptor` in the new schema to reference the required CRS.

```
SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder builder = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
AttributeTypeBuilder attributeBuilder = new AttributeTypeBuilder();
builder.setName(schema.getName());
builder.setSuperType((SimpleFeatureType) schema.getSuper());

List<AttributeDescriptor> attributes = schema.getAttributeDescriptors();

for (AttributeDescriptor attrib : attributes) {
  AttributeType type = attrib.getType();
  if (type instanceof GeometryType) {
    if (schema.getCoordinateReferenceSystem() == null) {
      // need to set the crs
      DefaultGeographicCRS crs = DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84;
      builder.setCRS(crs);
      GeometryDescriptor g = schema.getGeometryDescriptor();
      attributeBuilder.init(g);
      attributeBuilder.setCRS(crs);
      GeometryDescriptor att = (GeometryDescriptor) attributeBuilder.buildDescriptor(g.getLocalName());
      builder.add(att);
      builder.setDefaultGeometry(att.getLocalName());
    } else {
      builder.add(attrib);
      builder.setDefaultGeometry(attrib.getLocalName());
    }
  } else {
    builder.add(attrib);
  }
}
```

Comment: The `GeometryDescriptor` info was really helpful. Thanks Ian :)